# Calculate centre point of rectangle in flex

Tags: apache-flex, rect

I have two rectangles:

var rect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(66,147,89,67);

var rect2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(155,147,89,67);

How to calculate the centre point of these rectangles based on their x and y positions. I want the centre point to be calculated with relative to stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Global Way.
First you need to find the minimum and maximum points of your shapes in this case rectangles.
Than you need to use min.x+(max.x-min.x)/2 and min.y+(max.y-min.y)/2

here is code how to do that.

```
var rects:Array={rectangle1,rectangle2}
var min:Point=new Point(Number.MAX_VALUE,NUMBER.MAX_VALUE)
var max:Point=new Point(Number.MIN_VALUE,NUMBER.MIN_VALUE)
foreach(var rect:rectangle in rects)
{
    min.x=Math.min(min.x,rect.left);
    min.y=Math.min(min.y,rect.top);
    max.x=Math.max(max.x,rect.right);
    max.y=Math.max(max.y,rect.bottom);
}
```

var center:Point=new Point(min.x+(max.x-min.x)/2,min.y+(max.y-min.y)/2)
if your rectangles are in another container rather than stage
you can call
contaner.localToGLobal(center) the result is point that is position relative to stage

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple - first define boundaries of a third rectangle, that covers both of the rectangles and calculate the center of that rectangle.

```
var left:Number = rect1.x < rect2.x ? rect1.x : rect2.x;
var right:Number = rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x + rect2.width ? rect1.x + rect1.width - left : rect2.x + rect2.width - left;
var top:Number = rect1.y < rect2.y ? rect1.y : rect2.y;
var bottom:Number = rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y + rect2.height ? rect1.y + rect1.height - top : rect2.y + rect2.height - top;

var centerX:Number = left + 0.5 * right;
var centerY:Number = top + 0.5 * bottom;
```

Comment: I am not getting you. I want to know the centre point of both the rectangles

Comment: `centerX` and `centerY` are coordinates of the center point of the both rectangles.